# Replacing DataContract serialization with Binary one in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, azure

Azure Service Fabric uses `DataContract` serialization, which is a total disaster – it violates LSP [(wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) - see all those `KnownTypeAttribute` things, making framework development basically impossible.

I made the following class be a parent of all `ValueObject` to convince Service Fabric actually consume Binary serialization when it thinks about Data Contract one:

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable]
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptOut)]
public abstract class SerializableObject
{
    [DataMember]
    [JsonIgnore]
    byte[] State { get; set; }
    static object Recursive { get; } = new object();

    [OnSerializing()]
    void OnSerializing(StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (context.Context == Recursive)
            return;

        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter(null, new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.Other, Recursive));
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, this);
            State = stream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    [OnDeserialized()]
    void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        if (State == null)
            return;

        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(State))
            Assign(formatter.Deserialize(stream));
    }

    void Assign(object obj)
    {
        foreach (var property in GetType()
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite))
            property.SetValue(this, property.GetValue(obj));
    }
}
```

So, actual objects could be something like this:

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public class PacketRecieved : SerializableObject 
{
    public PacketRecieved(DeviceId deviceId, InboundPacket packet)
    {
        DeviceId = deviceId;
        Packet = packet;
    }

    public DeviceId DeviceId { get; private set; }
    public InboundPacket Packet { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You should probably remove empty braces inside attributes. `[OnSerializing()]` => `[OnSerializing]`.
2. This loop is very hard to read due to how you use offsets.

   > ```
   > foreach (var property in GetType()
   >         .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
   >         .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite))
   >         property.SetValue(this, property.GetValue(obj));
   > ```

   Mainly because it is impossible to tell at first glace where `foreach` statement ends and loop body begins. Use offsets to separate them:

   ```
   foreach (var property in GetType()
                           .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                           .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite))
       property.SetValue(this, property.GetValue(obj));
   ```

   Or just add `{ }` braces (that's what I would do).
3. `State` is probably not the best name for a property, its too generic. Maybe `SerializedState` or `BinaryData` would do a better job at explaining its purpose.
4. It would be nice to have some control over which properties are deserialized. You know, similar to how you can use `XmlIgnore` attribute to skip a property during xml (de-)serialization.
5. Unless what you do should be completely obvious to anyone working with Azure, you should add some basic documentation. I am not familiar with Azure, and to me it is unclear what problem you are trying to solve, why do you solve it using inheritance as opposed to using separate non-abstract binary serializer or wtf `Recursive` property is used for. You might want to explain some of those things in your code using xml-documentation.